# Shopware language bar in the topbar

Tags: shopware6

I have a request,

at the moment i have this code for showing the language selection on my website

```
{% block layout_header_actions_language_widget%}
    {% if position is empty %}
        {% set position = 'top-bar' %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if  page.header.languages.count > 1 %}
        <div class="top-bar-nav-item top-bar-language">
            {% block layout_header_actions_language_widget_form %}
                <form method="post"
                      action="{{ path('frontend.checkout.switch-language') }}"
                      class="language-form"
                      data-form-auto-submit="true">

                    {% block layout_header_actions_language_widget_form_csrf %}
                        {{ sw_csrf('frontend.checkout.switch-language') }}
                    {% endblock %}

                    {% block layout_header_actions_language_widget_content %}
                        {% set isoCode = page.header.activeLanguage.translationCode.code|lower|split('-') %}
                        {% set country = isoCode[0] %}
                        {% set language = isoCode[1] %}

                        <div class="languages-menu dropdown">
                            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle top-bar-nav-btn"
                                    type="button"
                                    id="languagesDropdown-{{ position }}"
                                    {{ dataBsToggleAttr }}="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="top-bar-list-icon language-flag country-{{ country }} language-{{ language }}"></div>
                                <span class="top-bar-nav-text">{{ page.header.activeLanguage.name }}</span>
                            </button>
                            {% block layout_header_actions_languages_widget_form_items %}
                                <div class="top-bar-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                                    aria-labelledby="languagesDropdown-{{ position }}">
                                    {% for language in  page.header.languages %}
                                            <div class="top-bar-list-item dropdown-item{% if language.id is same as(page.header.activeLanguage.id) %} item-checked{% endif %}"
                                                 title="{{ language.translated.name }}">

                                                {% block layout_header_actions_languages_widget_form_items_flag %}
                                                    {% set isoCode = language.translationCode.code|lower|split('-') %}
                                                    {% set flagCountry = isoCode[0] %}
                                                    {% set flagLanguage = isoCode[1] %}

                                                    <label class="top-bar-list-label"
                                                           for="{{ position }}-{{ language.id }}">
                                                        <input id="{{ position }}-{{ language.id }}"
                                                               class="top-bar-list-radio"
                                                               value="{{ language.id }}"
                                                               name="languageId"
                                                               type="radio"
                                                            {% if language.id is same as(page.header.activeLanguage.id) %} checked{% endif %}>
                                                        <div class="top-bar-list-icon language-flag country-{{ flagCountry }} language-{{ flagLanguage }}"></div>
                                                        {{ language.name }}
                                                    </label>
                                                {% endblock %}
                                            </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>

                        <input name="redirectTo" type="hidden" value="{{ app.request.get('_route') }}"/>

                        {% for key, value in app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
                            <input name="redirectParameters[{{ key }}]" type="hidden" value="{{ value }}">
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </form>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

but actually i need it just to be side by side

so in my case Dutch | English and the text is the button, the above code is for showing it in a dropdown listing.

does anyone have a simple solution?

i tried to show it in just a label format but i am not really sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override `layout_header_actions_language_widget_content` and remove the dropdown specific elements. Tested this and the elements seem to work fine outside of the dropdown. You'll likely just have to adjust the styling to your needs.

```html
{% block layout_header_actions_language_widget_content %}
    {% set isoCode = page.header.activeLanguage.translationCode.code|lower|split('-') %}
    {# @deprecated tag:v6.5.0 - Remove else cases, to maintain correct split of isoCode #}
    {% set language = feature('v6.5.0.0') ? isoCode[0] : isoCode[1] %}
    {% set country = feature('v6.5.0.0') ? isoCode[1] : isoCode[0] %}

    {% for language in  page.header.languages %}
        <div class="btn top-bar-list-item {% if language.id is same as(page.header.activeLanguage.id) %} item-checked{% endif %}"
             title="{{ language.translated.name }}">

            {% block layout_header_actions_languages_widget_form_items_flag %}
                {% set isoCode = language.translationCode.code|lower|split('-') %}
                {# @deprecated tag:v6.5.0 - Remove else cases, to maintain correct split of isoCode #}
                {% set flagLanguage = feature('v6.5.0.0') ? isoCode[0] : isoCode[1] %}
                {% set flagCountry = feature('v6.5.0.0') ? isoCode[1] : isoCode[0] %}

                <label class="top-bar-list-label"
                       for="{{ position }}-{{ language.id }}">
                    <input id="{{ position }}-{{ language.id }}"
                           class="top-bar-list-radio"
                           value="{{ language.id }}"
                           name="languageId"
                           type="radio"
                        {% if language.id is same as(page.header.activeLanguage.id) %} checked{% endif %}>
                    <div class="top-bar-list-icon language-flag country-{{ flagCountry }} language-{{ flagLanguage }}"></div>
                    {{ language.name }}
                </label>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <input name="redirectTo" type="hidden" value="{{ app.request.get('_route') }}"/>

    {% for key, value in app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
        <input name="redirectParameters[{{ key }}]" type="hidden" value="{{ value }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much. one more question is there a way to use a separator | in between?

Comment: Try putting `{% if not loop.last %}<span>|</span>{% endif %}` after the closing `div`.